# Razor view's bounded property not updating after post

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, razor-pages

I cannot get the property Price in the example razor view below to update after `OnPostOrder()` executes. I wrote this example view to do the following:

- On change of the product select list, submit the ProductForm using jquery's `submit()`.
- Use `asp-page-handler` to hit `OnPostOrder()` when the ProductForm is submitted. **Note**: this works in my implementation apologizes if there's a syntax problem in my example.
- I get all product options from a custom static function then get the matching product by productid.
- I set the matching product's price to the Price property. **However,** this doesn't update the Price property.

Example View:

```
@page
@{
    @functions{
        [BindProperty] public string Product { get; set; }
        [BindProperty] public decimal Price { get; set; }

        public void OnPostOrder()
        {
            Price = 25.00;
        }
    }
    List<ProductOption> productOptions = AdminUtil.GetProductOptions();
    SelectList productOptionSelectList = new SelectList(productOptions, "ProductId", "Name");
}

<form method="post" id="ProductForm" asp-page-handler="order">
    Product: <select asp-for="Product" asp-items="@productOptionSelectList"></select> <br />
    Order Amount: <input asp-for="Price" /> <br />
</form>

@section Scripts {
    <script>
        $(function () {
            $('#Product').on('change', function () {
                $("#ManualOrderForm").submit();
            });
        });
    </script>
}
```

I'm new to razor pages, so if this is a duplicate question please point me in the right direction. I haven't been able to find a comparable example, but I may not be searching the correct terms.

One reason that seems to make sense is that `asp-for` generates the HTML `name` and `value` attributes. But when I debug the page after `OnPostOrder()` I'm able to hit the `<input asp-for="OrderAmount" />`.

Comment: You are getting the Price by executing your `AdminUtil.GetProductOptions()` method and using the output of that. Debug that method call and see the method return expected value. Nothing to do with your form submit.

Comment: The price property does change I followed the break point there just now. Just not on the form.

Comment: I still do not understand what your expected behavior is.

Comment: I updated my `OnPostOrder()` to set the value to 25. pretend it was 0 before. After executing the `OnPostOrder()` method the value is still 0 on the form. Shouldn't that change the forms value as well.

Comment: Where are you expecting to see 25 in the form ? You are not currently printing the `Price` property value in your form. So where are you expecting it to be displayed ? Also your OnPost method should return something.

Comment: I’m expecting to see 25 in the price input. If the property is bound using asp-for like the Product property i should see its value change correct? That’s exactly what happens with the Product property.

Comment: Your input is bound to `OrderAmount`, not `Price`.

Comment: Sorry about that I’ll update my example code. The example is a condensed version on my razor view. Still the same result of no updated value. I’ve also returned Page() with the same result of no updated Price value.

Comment: I’m expecting to see it as the value attribute in the input html element where asp-for=Price is used

Answer (score 26, accepted):

This is happening because when rendering the input element markup, the input tag helper first check model state dictionary for any values and if it finds a value for this property, that will be used. That is the reason you are seeing the original value passed from the input element via your form submit.

The solution is to remove this specific item from the model state dictionary. You can use the `ModelState.Remove` method to do so.

```
public IActionResult OnPost()
{       
    this.Price = 25;

    ModelState.Remove("Price");  // This line does the trick
    return Page();
}
```

I also suggest you to use the correct types for your properties. If you are dealing with numeric values, use a numeric type such as `int` or `decimal` instead of string.

Comment: I’m away from my computer. I will try that as soon as possible. Thanks for all the help.

Comment: This worked wonders, thank you! Price was a decimal by the way.

Comment: Wow... this is SOO hidden away. I've been struggling away with this for a couple of hours until I stumbled upon this post! Do you know of any references to read up on, regarding this?

Comment: I needed ModelState.Remove("Price"); Price = null; to make this work

Answer (score 0):

`this.StateHasChanged();`  worked nicely for me

```
public void OnPost()
{   
    this.Price = 25; //change value
    this.StateHasChanged(); //tells page to update
}
```