# Razor onPost update model but cannot update page

Tags: asp.net-core, razor, razor-pages

I have create the searchEntry Class as below:

```
public class BookEntry
{
    public string[] BookTypes { get; set; } = Array.Empty<string>();
    public string BookA { get; set; } = string.Empty;
    public string BookB { get; set; } = string.Empty;
}
```

In the view, I define this

```
public class BookSearchModel : PageModel
{
    public void OnGet()
    {}

    [BindProperty]
    public BookEntry? bookEntry { get; set; }
    public IActionResult OnPostCopy()
    {
        if (bookEntry !=null)
        {
            bookEntry.BookB = bookEntry.BookA;           
        }
        return Page();
    }
}
```

In the view I create the html as below:

```
<form asp-page-handler="copy" class="mb-3 mt-md-2" method="post">
    <div class="row g-3">
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <label asp-for="bookEntry.BookA" class="form-label">Book A</label>
            <input asp-for="bookEntry.BookA" class="form-control" />
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <label asp-for="bookEntry.BookB" class="form-label">Book B</label>
            <input asp-for="bookEntry.BookB" class="form-control" />
        </div>
    </div>
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
    <div class="row g-3">
       <div>Result Book A: @Model.bookEntry!.BookA</div>
       <div>Result Book B: @Model.bookEntry!.BookB</div>
    </div>
</form>
```

When I type "apple" in bookEntry.BookA and click submit, I check it can trigger OnPostCopy() function,
and then the return page, the bottom div tag can show
Result Book A: apple, Result Book b: apple
But the textbox value of bookEntry.BookB is empty

Can I know what's problem inside?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Razor view's bounded property not updating after post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54356921/razor-views-bounded-property-not-updating-after-post)

Answer (score 1):

When binding data in client side,it will get value from ModelState prior to Model .Try to add `ModelState.Clear();` into your code:

```
public IActionResult OnPostCopy()
        {
            if (bookEntry != null)
            {
                ModelState.Clear();
                bookEntry.BookB = bookEntry.BookA;
            }
            return Page();
        }
```

result:
[image]